# Creating a Custom Market Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, yfinance

I am a complete beginner with Python. I need to create a custom market index with 50 tickers. I have the tickers in a list and was able to retrieve price and market cap data. However, I am not able to figure out how to pull the price and market cap data for each individual stock for a 2 year historical period. After this is complete, I will need to sum the market cap data and divide each ticker's mkt cap to find a weighting. I will need to multiply the weighting by each stock price to find the daily index value for the prior two years. I think I can figure out how to do the last few steps but I need the data in order to start. Once I do this, I will need to pull the index value of ^SPX for the same time period and benchmark the custom index to it and graph (I think I can do this).

All the tickers are in a list in `tickers_list`. My last attempt was the closest using:

```
all_symbols = " ".join(ticker_list)
myInfo = Ticker(all_symbols)
myDict = myInfo.price

for ticker in ticker_list:
    ticker = str(ticker)
    market_cap = myDict[ticker]['marketCap'],start,end
    price = myDict[ticker]['regularMarketPrice'],start,end
    print(ticker, market_cap, price)
```

Output:

> MMS (4936236032, '2021-05-01', '2023-05-01') (81.21, '2021-05-01', '2023-05-01')
> TYL (16606191616, '2021-05-01', '2023-05-01') (396.09, '2021-05-01', '2023-05-01')
> LRN (1798243584, '2021-05-01', '2023-05-01') (41.7825, '2021-05-01', '2023-05-01')
> (and onwards for all 50 tickers)

I don't think this is what I am looking to do as I'm not sure how to manipulate the data in such a way to begin finding the index value.